# PHP - Show more from user with more percentage

Tags: php

on our Site we have an Animation, that spins the Avatars from Users. The problem is, that this was really random. If user1 has more (1.00$) and user2 (0.50$), it can show more user2 avatars in the animation, than the user1.

The Avatars gets pushed in the array here (in value you get the amount)

```
SELECT avatar, SUM(value) FROM `game".$gamenum."` GROUP BY `value` DESC
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $crd .= 'avatar.push(\''.$row["avatar"].'\');';
    $i++;
}
```

and now here it gets random on the 44 Positions in the animation

```
for(var i=1; i <= 44; i++) {
    var rand = getRandomInt(0,(avatar.length-1));
    $(\'#img\'+i).attr("src",avatar[rand]); 
}
```

and this is the "getRandomInt" function

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

I tried a much, but i dont find anything how to show the Avartars like the Percentage of the full amount

The Full amount in this example is: 1.50$. Like the amount from user1 + user2.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: In your initial MySQL query, why do you group by values?

Comment: @Nvj that is what i am testing... but it gets out the same like before... before i have without value. With group value i have the same... that doing nothing other

Comment: You want to display the percent of an avatar along with its name, correct?

Comment: I have 44 Images, on every image must be one Avatar from one User. But i will show more Avatars from User, who has more percentage in full amount. In this Example i will show 75% Avatars of user1, and 25% from user2, cause user1 has 1.00$ and user2 has 0.50. And full Amount is 1.50$. You know? 

In my code, all gets random and it can be show more from user2 than user1, cause he only insert randomly, and not by amount of value

Comment: I've tried to answer your question from what I could understand of your question. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to order the user's by their value in your MySQL query, instead of "grouping" them by value. Instead, if `avatar` is not the unique key, you should group by it.

You also need the sum of all values of all users. Calculate that in the while loop below.

```
SELECT avatar, SUM(value) FROM `game".$gamenum."` ORDER BY `value` DESC
$sum = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $crd .= 'avatar.push(\''.$row["avatar"].'\');';
    $i++;
    $sum += $row["value"];
}
```

After this, you probably pass the avatar array and the total $sum value to JavaScript (front-end).

On the front-end side, instead of looping through the 44 images, loop through the avatars.

You also need to keep track of whether all the 44 images have been filled. In that case, we will need to end the loop.

```
// Keep track of number of images inserted
var imagesInserted = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < avatars.length; i++)
{        
    // Get avatar's value. Assuming that your JavaScript array contains the avatar's value at the second index and name at the first inde
    var val = avatar[i][1];

    // Get avatar's percent share in the 44 images
    var n = getImagesShare(avatar[i][1], sumOfAllAvatars);

    // Check whether 44 images are over


    if(imagesInserted <= 44)
    {
        // Code to insert 'n' images for this user

        // Increment the number of images inserted
        imagesInserted += n;
    }
    else
    {
        // All 44 images have been inserted, end the loop
        i = avatars.length + 1;
    }
}
```

Finally, the function to calculate the number of images a user should get:

```
function getImagesShare(avatarValue, totalValue)
{
    var numberOfImages = Math.floor((avatarValue/totalValue) * 44);
    return numberOfImages;
}
```

The above is a basic implementation based on your code. Performance wise, you should do most of the processing related to displaying the number of images for each user on back-end side, and only display the data on the front-end side, in addition to some more functionality if needed.